# Movimentos da activity no Android

Tags: android, android-activity

Desenvolvi um aplicação parecida com o 2048 e está funcionando aparentemente bem.
Porém tem um detalhe que está me incomodando.

1 - Eu tenho uma tela(Activity)  em cima da tela tenho vários botões esses botões representam aqueles quadros onde aparecem os números no jogo 2048.

2 - Quando estou jogando, os movimentos que realizo( deslizo para esquerda, deslizo para direita, para cima e para baixo ) são pegos pela activity e são tratados perfeitamente.

Quando os movimentos citados acima, são iniciados ou finalizados em cima dos botões a minha activity não capta o movimento realizado.

Oque posso fazer para resolver isso ??

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas acredito que apenas desabilitar os botões já resolve o seu problema, não?

Comment: Olá amigo, deixando a propriedade clickable nos botões como false parece que resolveu o problema. Obrigado